# Decrypting gpg2-symmetrically-encrypted files using non-gpg2 tools

Tags: aes, gnupg

If I encrypt a file using `gpg2` and specifying AES256 as my encryption algorithm, can I decrypt it with tools other than `gpg2`?

More generally, does the fact that one tool used AES256 for encrypting a file imply that any other tool that also supports AES256 can decrypt the file?

Comment: Well, of course you can use GPG version 1, and any number of things that use or wrap (either version of) GPG for example Kleopatra; I don't know if you count those as 'other'. As I commented to user10216038 answer, PGP uses a particular mode and key derivation, and also a particular file/message format, that differ from other crypto systems and are not supported by tools designed for e.g. SMIME/CMS, SSL/TLS, SSH, and so on. But there are other implementations of PGP including Phil Z's original (now Symantec) and libraries in at least Java, Perl, PHP, Python, and Ruby you can use.

Answer (score 1):

AES256 is a standard algorithm. Any tool that correctly implements a standard is interchangeable.

That said, a given tool may append decorators before and after that might need to be stripped out or altered for another tool, but the core encryption is the same.

Comment: AES itself is indeed standard, but PGP uses it in a variant of CFB mode (prefix block instead of IV, plus a 2-byte 'stutter' for quick key verification) that no one else uses. Also it uses a key _derived_ from the password by a string-to-key (s2k) operation no one else uses.